# Как вызвать функцию с диалоговым окном из сторонней dll внутри Qt слота

Tags: c++, qt

К моей программе на Qt статически подключена сторонняя dll. В dll есть метод, который содержит диалоговое окно. Этот метод вызывается в слоте:

```
void reportForm::showDialog_Slot()
{
    // Вызываем метод из dll с диалоговым окном
    showExtDialog(); 
}
```

Диалоговое окно открывается, но через несколько секунд всё само закрывается вместе с моим приложением.

Я знаю, что вызывать диалоговое окно нужно обязательно методом exec(), иначе диалог сразу закроется, поскольку слот отработает, а диалог в данном случае создан на стеке метода и по завершению метода диалог уничтожится.
Но как быть, если диалоговое окно вызывается в функции из dll?

Answer (score 0):

Вызывать диалоговое окно методом `exec()` совсем не обязательно. Этот метод только делает модальным окно, блокирует действия пользователя пока он не закроет окно, а также блокирует дальнейшее выполнение кода.

В [документации](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec) к `exec()`, есть замечание использовать другую [функцию](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#open) : `open()`, которая делает тоже самое что и `exec()` но является асинхронной.

В вашем случае, как я понимаю, нужно обязательно выйти из функции `showExtDialog()`, поэтому попробуйте сделайте так:

```
 //где-то в dll
 void showExtDialog(QObject* parent)
 {
      QDialog* dialog = new Dialog(parent);
      dialog->open();
 }

 void reportForm::showDialog_Slot()
 {
      // Вызываем метод из dll с диалоговым окном
      showExtDialog(this); 
 }
```

Утечек не будет, потому-что вы передали `parent`,  и при уничтожении `reportForm` уничтожится и созданное диалоговое окно. Однако здесь есть минус: нужно гарантировать что сначала вызовется деструкор `reportForm` а потом выгрузится библиотека.

Или можно изменить `showExtDialog` так чтобы он возвращал указатель на созданный диалог, и вызывающий код сам управлял бы временем жизни объекта.

Comment: Может быть я ошибаюсь, но при статическом подключении библиотека не загружается/выгружается. Это устраняется указанный Вами "минус"?

Comment: Если это dll, то она всегда загружается и выгружается. Но ее можно линковать статически, тогда она будет загружаться автоматически при старте приложения и также автоматически выгружатся, и это устраняет минус. Минус про который я говорил скорее относится к случаю, когда dll загружается динамически(через `LoadLibrary` под windows например).

Comment: Я так понял, что `showExtDialog` - это библиотечная функция. А библиотека сторонняя. Почему тогда вы предлагаете исправить функцию DLL?

Comment: @maestro  если есть доступ к коду, то его всегда можно форкнуть, к тому же, я не вижу другого способа. Можно конечно через поток решить это вопрос, но думаю корректней менять dll (то что библиотека сторонняя может много чего значить не факт что автор вопроса не имеет такой возможности), или отказываться от такой библиотеки.